# Install remotely with powershell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, automation, powershell-remoting, wsh

I want to build a script that will Install remotely HP OM agent. Is there any good way to Install it, without having the install files on the remote computer? 
this script will install remotely the HP agents for list of servers. I thought to copy the files from my computer to each server and after that to install it. I'm sure there is a better way to do it.
To install the agent I need to run the command : 
cscript "\c:\pathToTheAgentFile" -i -a -minprecheck

Comment: Can you tell us what PowerShell version is available on the remote computers?

Comment: Its between 2-3 , on my computer it's 4. Is there suppose to any diffrence ?

Comment: Yes, available cmdlets and other features that will impact how the script is created.

Comment: What version do I need ?

Comment: Any version can work, knowing what version that is available will limit what cmdlets can be used and impact other considerations.

Comment: PowerShell DSC was built to solve this problem.

Comment: some of the servers are 2003r2 and 2008r2 , I cant use PowerShell DSC on them

Answer (score 0):

Using Invoke-Command with the ScriptBlock parameter should accomplish this task so long as a silent install method is used.

```
$ComputersList = @("computer","names","here","replace","me")
$PathToShare = "\\path\to\install_replace_me.exe"
$CommonLocalComputerPath = "C:\replace_me.exe"
$SilentInstallArgs = "/example","/replace"
$AdministratorCreds = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty

$ComputersList | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { Copy-Item $Using:PathToShare -Destination $Using:CommonLocalComputerPath -Credential $Using:AdministratorCreds;
    Start-Process $Using:CommonLocalComputerPath -ArgumentList $Using:SilentInstallArgs -Credential $Using:AdministratorCreds} -Credential $AdministratorCreds
}
```

The above script will prompt for administrative credentials, authenticate to a remote share that holds the installer from the remote computer, copy the installer to the remote computer, and then start the installer on the remote computer. You will have to verify the installs manually as it will not return any data except in the event of a terminating error. The script will have to be modified to point to the correct locations for your environment.

Comment: To install the agent I neeed to run the command : cscript path -i -a -minprechek , where should I put it in teh script ?

Comment: can you tell what to put in the $SilentInstallArgs?
how I put my user in the $AdministratorCreds?
what are the difference between   $PathToShare and $CommonLocalComputerPath ?
I don't see any place in your script that you call the  $ComputersList

Comment: What you will place in $SilentInstallArgs is based on the arguments required for the HP OM agent to install silently, I do not know them. When you run the script from you computer you will be prompted for the credentials automatically, the credentials must be ones that have install access on the servers. $PathToShare is the location of the installer for the HP OP agent that the servers can access. $CommonLocalComputerPath is the place the servers will put the copy of the HP OM installer from the share location. The $ComputerList was a typo, I have fixed that.